# extract data that has both patterns

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

I need some help on one of my assignments , the scenario : we have data files -- eg bus company info : ( location id and company office/depot )

```
id^office
B003^Red Bus Off BSR - GPO
B015^Red Bus Depot BSR
B003^Red Bus Off BSR - Main Stand
B027^MCD Bus Depot LLR
B047^MCD Bus Depot BSR
```

....  etc

i need to extract data that has both "Red Bus" (Company Name) and "Depot" in the office name not others ..... hence in the output file only 
     B015^Red Bus Depot BSR

i was currently trying egrep "pat1|pat2" but that works for OR condition , i have also tried if- then grep/sed -- that dosent work well with what is required as i get results that are satisfy either of the patterns and not both !

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can the use logical `AND` with `awk` using the `&&` operator like so:

```
$ awk '/Red Bus/&&/Depot/' file
B015^Red Bus Depot BSR
```

But you data shows not reason not to do:

```
$ fgrep 'Red Bus Depot' file
B015^Red Bus Depot BSR
```

Note: `fgrep` is just fixed string grep (i.e `grep -F`) as regexps aren't required.

If you can't guarantee only a space will separate `Red Bus` and `Depot` but can guarantee the order then:

```
$ grep 'Red Bus.*Depot' file
B015^Red Bus Depot BSR
```

Finally if you can't guarantee the order:

```
$ egrep 'Red Bus.*Depot|Depot.*Red Bus' file
B015^Red Bus Depot BSR
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/Red Bus/{/Depot/p}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

try piping. `grep "Red Bus" <File> |grep Depot`  Basically you grep for all "Red bus", and among those result, search for which have "Depot", this effectively creates an and condition